# Show only unique results within core data NSFetchResultController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary

I wish to show only unique results from the core data fetch request. Currently from research I have seen it is possible to achieve this from using `NSDictionaryResultType` but I have struggled to get it working.

I did try using the following but couldn't intergrate it correctly into my class. I was not 100% sure what to put after `NSArray *distincResults` as it came up unused variable:

```
     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Routines" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
 request.entity = entity;
 request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"routinename"]];
 request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
 request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"routinename" ascending:YES];
 [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

 NSError *error = nil;
 NSArray *distincResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
 // Use the results
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should not dump the whole code of your class. Just quote the necessary parts. Please revise your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `NSDictionaryResultType`, you cannot use the FRC delegate to watch for changes. If that is OK, you can go down this route.

Once you have an array of dictionaries (`distinctResults`) make that the data array of your table view. So, for example, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `configureCell`, use

```
cell.textLabel.text = distinctResults[indexPath.row][@"routinename"];
```

This is the short form of

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[distinctResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                          objectForKey:@"routinename"];
```

Comment: See my edit above. You have to change the datasource methods of your controller.

Comment: yeah I know about the configureCell, however I am getting a warning on the `NSArray *distincResults` that comes up unused variable. The tableview is empty.

Comment: NSLOG is coming back as nill :/

Comment: You need to make your results array the available to the whole class. With fetched results controller, this is very easy. Just use `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects`. Otherwise declare an array for your class and fill it in `viewDidLoad` with your fetch.